# java jdbc xml sql condtional with in cdata

Tags: java, sql, xml, spring, if-statement

Hi I am very new to Java and have inherited a spring pattern. I want to know if there is a way to do a conditional in the xml.

Here is the scenario

```
<value>
  <![CDATA[
      SELECT * FROM table WHERE a=:a
  ]]
</value>
```

Here is what I want to do base on a global flag

```
<value>
  <![CDATA[
      SELECT * FROM table WHERE a=:a
   <if global >
      AND b=:b
   </if>
  ]]
</value>
```

I am not sure about the syntax or it this is even possible inside of CDATA

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. But you can do it in Java, by splitting your query in parts in xml, wire them into your class and then do string concatenation based on an if statement in Java.